# Inheritance in Java (default constructor)

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider there are three classes A, B and C. Class A doesn't have a constructor,  ClassB has a constructor and Class C has a parameterized constructor. something like the example given below.

---

```
public class ClassA {

}
```

---

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    public ClassB() {
        System.out.println("Default cons Class B");
    }

}
```

---

```
public class ClassC extends ClassB {

    public ClassC(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("This is class C "+a+ "and"+ b );

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ClassC c = new ClassC(2,3);
    }
}
```

---

Output:

Default cons Class C

This is class C 2and3

Question 1:

To construct object C it constructs B and to construct B it constructs A first. Even though there isn't any default constructor in class A defined, the program works fine by construction its own default constructor and the B class calls super(). I don't have an issue here however when I change the Class B something like this

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    public ClassB(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("This is class C "+a+ "and"+ b );
    }   
}
```

I am getting an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Implicit super constructor ClassB() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

    at ClassC.<init>(ClassC.java:4)
    at ClassC.main(ClassC.java:10)
```

Why do we have to implicitly specify the super constructor ClassB(), It worked fine for the first example even though there isn't any super constructor in ClassA(). I am wondering if by default the C's constructor by default calls B's unspecified constructor just like it did for Class A.

Comment: A default constructor does not need to be defined, as long as you don't define another constructor, it will contain public ClassA()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify at least one constructor in a class a default constructor is no longer created for you.

If you do not specify which parent constructor to call in your subclass the one that takes 0 parameters is used by default.

Since you added a constructor to class B that takes two integer parameters you now have to call it like this from in C as there is no longer a constructor that takes no parameters in class B:

```
public ClassC(int a, int b) {
    super(a, b);
    System.out.println("This is class C "+a+ "and"+ b );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because to create an instance of C, the JVM calls the constructors of the class hierarchy.

So when you create `C`, you actually first call the constructor of `A`, then of `B`, then of `C`. Implicitly, `super()` is called if nothing else is specified.

If you create a constructor that takes parameters explicitly, then that overrides the default constructor

```
public B() {
    //default constructor
}
```

Which means Java won't be able to invoke it for you implicitly as it does not exist, so you have to call it yourself with

```
public C(int a, int b) {
    super(a, b);
}
```